# Ссылка на партнёра

Tags: php, wordpress, поисковая-оптимизация

Имеется плагин, который парсит записи с сайта-партнёра, и сохраняет эти записи в новом произвольном типе, допустим custom_type.

Эти скопированные записи нужны только для SEO и чтобы выводить ссылки на эти скопированные записи, допустим, в боковом меню, или под контентом. И если кликнуть по этой ссылке, тогда должен быть переход на соответствующую запись партнёра.

Для перехода на сайт партнёра использую хук post_type_link

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_link', 1, 2);

function custom_post_type_link($link, $post){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'custom_type' ){
        $partnerLink = get_option('partner_link');
        $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true);
        return $partnerLink . $link;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что должно записываться в поле базы данных guid?

Т.е. если использовать хук post_type_link, тогда при копировании записей с сайта-партнёра в поле guid будет записываться примерно так:

```
http://partner-site.ru/title-post   //$partnerLink . $link
```

а если убрать хук post_type_link, тогда при копировании в поле guid будет записываться как обычно, в зависимости от выбранного способа отображения постоянных ссылок в настойках.

Подскажите, как правильно делать переадресацию и что записывать в поле guid базы данных?

/////////////
Парсер с помощью curl собирает записи с сайта-партнёра в массив.
Потом в цикле из этого массива создаются скопированные записи в новый тип custom_type.

```
//foreach
$args = array(
    'post_title'   => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_type'    => 'custom_type',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
);

if(!($post_id = wp_insert_post(wp_slash($args)))) continue;
```

Comment: Приведенный код не имеет никакого отношения к guid. Кроме того, записывать guid функциями WP невозможно - нет таких. Только "вручную" прямой записью поля в базе данных. Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, что именно вас беспокоит на странице? Покажите, как вы выводите custom_type на страницу и что не устраивает в полученном html.

Comment: >Приведенный код не имеет никакого отношения к guid.

Comment: Как это не имеет отношения?!
Я ведь говорил, что если убрать хук post_type_link, тогда в поле guid пишется совсем другая информация

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: а как вы проверяете, что в guid? и какая там информация в случае 1 и в случае 2?

Comment: @KAGG Design, про это я сказал в вопросе, т.е. что будет в guid.

Comment: http://partner-site.ru/title-post   //$partnerLink . $link

Comment: Разве этого нет? а если убрать хук, тогда будет как-то так: http://mysite.ru/custom_type/title

Comment: >а как вы проверяете, что в guid?

Comment: т.е. по вашему зайти в phpmyadmin и посмотреть, что находится в поле guid для этого нужно иметь сверх интеллект?

Comment: обижаться не надо, тут разные люди приходят. Иногда путают термины. OK, а как guid присутствует в html? Его там вообще быть не должно, если вы выводите только ссылки из get_option('partner_link');

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58177/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).